# Geting error while configuring jest in my angular project

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm getting error while configuring jest in my angular project
error is[image]

till now i have configured some steps
my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
    globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup',
    
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
    
    },
  };
```

2. Also deleted test file and removed object form angular.json

Comment: did u solve this problem ?